# $objWriter->save('unique.csv'); not saving file PHPExcel

Tags: php, csv, phpexcel, duplicates

I'm removing duplicate rows from a csv file and saving it into new file.

see my code, i tried to `print_r()` everywhere...

it is working good everywhere, but it does not save **sample.csv**

```
    <?php
    require'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


    function checkExtension($inputFileName) {
      if (pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION) == "csv") {
         $inputFileType = 'CSV';
         $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

         return $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
       } else {
        return $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
       }
    }


  function removeDuplicates($inputFileName, $objPHPExcel) {
     $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
     $urn = array();

    foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $rowIndex = $row->getRowIndex();
        $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell('B'.$rowIndex)->getValue();
        array_push($urn, $cellValue);
    }

    $numberOfURNs = count($urn);

    for ($rowIndex = $numberOfURNs; $rowIndex != 1; $rowIndex--) {
        $cellValue = $worksheet->getCell('B'.$rowIndex)->getValue();
        for ($i = $rowIndex - 2; $i != 0; $i--) {

          if ($urn[$i] == $cellValue) {
              $worksheet->removeRow($rowIndex);
              $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'CSV');
              $objWriter->save('unique.csv');
              break;
          }
        }
   }
     return $objPHPExcel = checkExtension('unique.csv');
  }



  $objPHPExcel=checkExtension('original.csv');
  $done=removeDuplicates('original.csv', $objPHPExcel);
    ?>
```

what am i doing wrong ? please help.

Comment: Problem is that you're trying to write a new file for every single cell..... move instantiating the writer and saving the file ___outside___ of your loops

Comment: And add a break after the removerow(), because you're removing the row several times (once for each cell in the row), so if your row has 10 cells, you're removing 10 rows